# How to configure laravel 5 and gclid

Tags: php, laravel-5, google-ads-api

How should I confugure laravel 5 with gclid ?

There is an article https: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2938246?hl=ru
When I try to pass a test parameter https://mysite.com.ua/?gclid=TeSter-123,
gclid becomes lowercase
https://mysite.com.ua/?gclid=tester-123

Perhaps there should be done something in htaccess ? 
Or maybe there are other ways?

Comment: `becomes lowercase` - do you mean it changes in the URL shown in your browser to lowercase?  What do your browser dev tools show, is there some redirect going on? What do you have in .htaccess now?

Comment: in htaccess there are a lot of redirects. But I figured  it redirects in public/index.php and changes url in lowercase

Answer (score 0):

There were a lot of redirects and in public/index.php there was a line where url was changed to lowercase. 
So htaccess is fine, the problem was in public/index.php.